# Open menu with two different buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-button

I have a very simple dropdown menu. By clicking on the icon NewIcon in DropdownMenu.Trigger, the user sees a drop-down menu. Everything is simple here. To implement the dropdown menu, I use the radix library (https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/dropdown-menu)

```
 <DropdownMenu.Root open={isOpen} onOpenChange={setIsOpen}>
  <DropdownMenu.Trigger>
      <NewIcon/>
  </DropdownMenu.Trigger>

  <DropdownMenu.Portal forceMount>
          <DropdownMenu.Content>
         ........here some components
          </DropdownMenu.Content>
  </DropdownMenu.Portal>
</DropdownMenu.Root>
```

However, I would like to also call this dropdown menu with another button (which is located in another component) on the same page.
For example, below is another component that renders the "Edit information" button. Tell me how to click on this button to open the dropdown menu

```
  <div>           
    <Button>
       Edit information
    </Button>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all you need to do is create a dispatcher that will switch the state to trigger a re-render of the page.

```html
const MyDropdownMenu = ({ isOpen, onToggle }) => (
  <DropdownMenu.Root open={isOpen} onOpenChange={onToggle}>
    <DropdownMenu.Trigger>
      <NewIcon />
    </DropdownMenu.Trigger>

    <DropdownMenu.Portal forceMount>
      <DropdownMenu.Content>
        {/*content */}
      </DropdownMenu.Content>
    </DropdownMenu.Portal>
  </DropdownMenu.Root>
);

const AnotherComponent = ({ onToggle }) => (
  <div>
    <Button onClick={onToggle}>
      Edit information
    </Button>

    <MyDropdownMenu isOpen={false} onToggle={onToggle} />
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setIsOpen((prevIsOpen) => !prevIsOpen);
  };

  return <AnotherComponent onToggle={toggleDropdown} />;
};

export default App;
```

You can use that with any state manager you prefer. The only thing that will change is the location where the data is stored.

Extended an example a bit according your comment.

```
    const MyDropdownMenu = ({ isOpen, onToggle }) => (

      const handler = () => {
        console.log(`MyDropdownMenu`);
        onToggle();
      }
      <DropdownMenu.Root open={isOpen} onOpenChange={handler}>
        <DropdownMenu.Trigger>
          <NewIcon />
        </DropdownMenu.Trigger>

        <DropdownMenu.Portal forceMount>
          <DropdownMenu.Content>
            {/*content */}
          </DropdownMenu.Content>
        </DropdownMenu.Portal>
      </DropdownMenu.Root>
    );

    const AnotherComponent = ({ onToggle }) => (
      const handler = () => {
        console.log(`MyDropdownMenu`);
        onToggle();
      }
      <div>
        <Button onClick={handler}>
          Edit information
        </Button>

        <MyDropdownMenu isOpen={false} onToggle={onToggle} />
      </div>
    );

    const App = () => {
      const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

      const toggleDropdown = () => {
        setIsOpen((prevIsOpen) => !prevIsOpen);
      };

      return <AnotherComponent onToggle={toggleDropdown} />;
    };

    export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question, but your example in the answer is not reproduced correctly. Tell me, where do we define the onToggle variable?

Comment: This is just an example, i tried to keep it simple. 

The main idea is to position the toggle handler above both of your components to share it with them and trigger a re-render when the state changes.

Please read [this](https://www.viking-js.com/post/understanding-smart-and-dumb-components-in-react), I believe it will help you understand what I am talking about.

Comment: Yes, I understood your idea, thanks. Tell me another question: in const MyDropdownMenu (from your code) I should display slightly different content (depending on which button MyDropdownMenu is called from). Please tell me, using your code as an example, how I can track which button opens MyDropdownMenu

Comment: What do you mean by "track"?

Comment: How can I find out (for example display in console with help console.log()) when clicking which button opened the menu

Comment: Add console.log within each onClick handler within the button. Wrap onToggle in an arrow function where you can include the log and onToggle together.

Comment: Could you show with an example of your code how to do this?

Comment: take a look at the answer. I have extended it

Answer (score 0):

The DropdownMenu's open state is controlled by `isOpen`

So you can just do this

```js
 <div>           
    <Button onClick={()=>setIsOpen(true)}>
       Edit information
    </Button>
  <div>
```